# C# DataGridView Row add dataGridView button text not change

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am reading xml file in winform and displaying data in DataGridView
DataGridView read in xml has a button, and when the button is clicked, the button's text is changed.

```
DataGridViewButtonCell btnStart = null;
btnStart = (DataGridViewButtonCell)(DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0]);
var btnType = btnStart.Value.ToString();
btnStart.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = false;
```

In this result I try to re-read the XML and append the ROW

```
DataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Is there a way to add ADD to the DataGridView without changing the text of the button in the DataGridView that is shown?

Comment: As John V’s answer notes, replacing the “whole” table in the grids data source is going to clear the values in the button column. In addition, where in the posted code does it try and “change” the buttons text value? The first code snippet grabs the grid’s button cell `btnStart`… then sets the button string value to a variable called `btnType` then does nothing with that value…? … In other words, … I do not see where the `btnStart.Value = SomeValue` is set…? …

Comment: The default value of btnStart in the code is start

Comment: if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) { if(btnType == "start"){   this.DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "stop"; }}

Comment: I am changing the btnType vlaue in this way

Comment: I am not sure why you did not post that code to begin with as it is pertinent. However, as noted already, even if the button value is set… it will be cleared when the grids "WHOLE" data source is changed. Adding a row to the grids data source will work.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code: `DataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];`

Doesn't read a row, it resets the entire `DataGridView`, which is why the button changes. If you want to append a row, then add a row to the Table the `DataGridView` is displaying, don't replace the whole thing.